# How to publish an Artifact from inside a Docker container

Tags: php, docker, teamcity, artifact

I'm running a TeamCity agent that spawns a docker container, running several tasks inside that (php) container. Such as phpunit, phplint and composer. I zipped the content inside the container if all tests pass, it will create a phpproject.zip.

After it's done I would like to push that phpproject.zip as an Artifact back to the TeamCity server from inside the docker container.

My docker container is running with the --rm parameters to remove the container after the script is done.

Is this possible?

Tim

Answer (score 6):

You can map a volume of the Docker daemon to the container with the `-v` parameter and publish the artifacts to the daemon:

```
...
# Your build path and build command here
VOLUME /foo/build
ENTRYPOINT make
```

In TeamCity, configure a Docker **build** step to build the Dockerfile, and name:tag the resulting image. Add a second step in which you configure an **other...** Docker command as `run`, with the *arguments*:

```
-v /tmp/build:/foo/build --rm <name of image>
```

The result is then available in `/tmp/build` on the agent, and you can configure that as artifact path in the project's settings, or alternatively `echo "##teamcity[publishArtifacts '/tmp/build']"` somewhere.

Comment: I think this could cause issues if two builds of the TeamCity job were run at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also do a

```
id=$(docker create <name of image>)
docker cp $id:/path-in-docker-container /path-on-server
docker kill $id
docker rm $id
```